# Web Analysis software with specific features

Tags: php, web-server, website, piwik

I am looking for a web analysis software that has the following features, in addition to the usual showing of visits, search keywords etc.

- Track individual visitor. The software use a unique cookie value to track visitors. I can find all the history that a visitor did on the site (assuming that the cookie is not deleted). And I can find out "who's on" from the software at any time (showing visitor IP, DNS name, browse history etc.).
- Track File downloaded from the web site, and display statistics.

Would prefer to an open source software (in PHP or ASP.Net).

Answer (score 2):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) might be what you are looking for. It's basically a free Google Analytics clone which you can run on your own infrastructure.

Comment: Google Analytics is free as well.

Comment: I meant free as in speech and not free as in beer but that was obviously not clear from the context. You are right, Google Analytics is free of monetary cost but it is not free software like Piwik.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics will do this. You need to configure some custom parameters to pass to the GA script.

The first parameter would be the individual's IP address or some unique identifier that you can create (a random string?). This you can generate on your web page at runtime (via PHP or .NET), or at client load time (via JavaScript). Once the page loads, the GA script will pick it up and log it on every page.

The second part -- tracking file downloads -- I don't think you need to do anything special for. GA will track the clicks. Alternatively, instead of linking directly to a file, have the user click a link to a page that triggers the download. The page will have tracking info on it so you can see in Google Analytics the stats.

Many / most other web analytics packages such as http://haveamint.com/ will do things like this as well.